# Uber Ride SDK for Swift 3.0

Tags: uber-api

I am working on application whose development language is Swift 3.1
I need to add uber apis  in application. I am trying it with cocoapods.
But current Uber Ride SDK is in Swift 2.3

Can anyone let me know about how can I integrate it in Swift 3.1 ?

Here I am sharing link of github which I am referring 
[Github Link](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Swift 3 Dev branch that you can use. It'll be merged back into master once we have time to clean up the API's a bit more after a current project.

https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/tree/swift-3-dev

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Do you have a timeframe on when it can be merged back to master. We don't want to point to dev branch for our production releases.